# Swift 2D array of String

Tags: arrays, swift

I want to create an array that holds two String arrays for a picker.  Each array needs to be 1 - 30 (Strings, not Ints)

I think I'm doing this right but Xcode disagrees:

```
var scorePickerArray: [[String]] = []

    for var i: Int = 0; i < 2; i++
        {
            for var j: Int = 0; j < 30; j++
            {
                scorePickerArray[i][j] = String(j + 1)
            }
        }
```

I'm getting an "array index out of bounds" for scorePickerArray[0][0]

What am I doing wrong?  (probably something very obvious)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version didn't work because when you ask for `scorePickerArray[0][0]`, the second dimension is not yet created, so it's "out of bounds", that is to say `scorePickerArray[0]` does not have members yet and you can't access them with subscript (`[0][0]`).

Solution:

```
var scorePickerArray = [[String]]()

var temp = [String]()

for i in 1...30 {
    temp.append("\(i)")
}

for i in 0...1 {
    scorePickerArray.append(temp)
}
```

Result:

> [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"], ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"]]

---

**Update for Swift 2**

A better solution for Swift 2 would be to use an array of Ints generated from a range (with each Int mapped to String) instead of loops:

```
let innerArray = Array(1...30).map { String($0) }
```

Then to repeat it like this:

```
let scorePickerArray = Array(count:2, repeatedValue: innerArray)
```